# Convert SVG with embedded image into PNG with Python

Tags: python, svg

My aim is to create PNG images from an svg with embedded (as a link) image.
I split the process in two: first create the SVGs, then my intention is to convert them to PNG.
The below successfully creates an svg file for each of the listed paths of a source SVG containing a linked image. It also correctly inserts the original image into the new files, however, each of the converted PNGs contain only the path, without the image.
Embedding the image as base64 is not an option as it is very heavy: I have already tried and the error was that it was too big (~13millions columns on one line), is there any other way to achieve the result?

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile
from lxml import etree

os.environ['path'] += r';C:\Program Files\Inkscape' #only way I found to have cairo work
import cairosvg

def create_svg_from_path(svg_path, output_folder):
    
    tree = etree.parse(svg_path)
    root = tree.getroot()

    
    width = root.get('width')
    height = root.get('height')

    
    image = root.find('.//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}image')

    if image is not None:
        # Get image attributes
        image_width = image.get('width')
        image_height = image.get('height')
        image_x = image.get('x')
        image_y = image.get('y')
        image_href = image.get('{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href')

        
        image_filename = os.path.basename(image_href)

        
        target_image_path = os.path.join(output_folder, image_filename)
        if not os.path.exists(target_image_path):
            # Assuming the script is in the same directory as the image file
            source_image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(svg_path)), image_filename)
            copyfile(source_image_path, target_image_path)

       
        for path in root.findall('.//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}path'):
            # Get the path ID
            path_id = path.get('id')

           
            output_svg_filename = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{path_id}.svg")

            
            new_root = etree.Element('svg', version="1.0", width=width, height=height, xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")

            
            new_image = etree.SubElement(new_root, 'image', attrib={
                'x': image_x, 'y': image_y,
                'width': image_width, 'height': image_height,
                '{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href': f"{image_filename}",
                'preserveAspectRatio': 'none'
            })

            
            group = etree.SubElement(new_root, 'g')

            
            new_path = etree.SubElement(group, 'path')
            new_path.attrib.update(path.attrib)

            
            with open(output_svg_filename, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(etree.tostring(new_root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8'))

            # Convert the SVG file to PNG
            output_png_filename = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{path_id}.png")
            cairosvg.svg2png(url=output_svg_filename, write_to=output_png_filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    input_svg_file ="file.svg"

    
    output_folder = "output_svgs"

    
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    
    create_svg_from_path(input_svg_file, output_folder)
```

Comment: Other than referring to the linked image by name, or embedding it as base64, how would you have this script include the image?

Comment: I was assuming that with cairo the full content of the svg (that is including the embedded image) would be transferred into the new PNG. I mean, manually this could be done in Inkscape, for example, by exporting the selection to PNG. I would need something like that, but without Inkscape involved or anything else that is not code

Comment: Ah I see - I misunderstood. I thought your aim was to create an .svg, but really you're just looking to convert the .svg to .png, like your title says. The question text suggested otherwise.

Comment: ok i will review to make it clearer

Comment: Since you already have Inkscape, have you considered running inkscape as a CLI application from Python? Something like `inkscape.exe --export-filename=file.png file.svg`? (additional options available https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html) Otherwise you'll just add up adding Cairo (and possibly GTK) to your script, which makes for a massive package install, that's not really adding anything.